# AJAX, PHP Copied Files not Found on Return to Browser

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-not-found

I am using 'jQuery AJAX PHP' to do some '.jpg' file copying (approx 330kb per file).  I copy files to a new directory location.

When I return to the HTML and use jQuery to add an IMG tag to a Table element, some of the files I have copied are shown as Not Found with 404 errors, but they are there.

I am wondering if it is a speed error.  I tried to slow down the return from the PHP, by reading the directory where the files had been copied to, but that did not seem to help.

Am I right in thinking it is a speed problem and does anyone have an idea as to how I may overcome this problem, because only by displaying the copied file, can I be certain it has been copied.

Comment: try increasing the timeout of ajax request.

Comment: Speed shouldn't be an issue here since you are returning after upload is complete. I smell wrong letter-case names here or a typo.

Comment: I am pretty certain they are there, as if I right click on the not found image and select show image in separate window, they are displayed and if I look at the directory with ftp, all the files are there.

Comment: @GeoPhoenix  I will try Timeout tomorrow, when I work out the syntax - thanks

Comment: @GeoPhoenix.  Timeout did not make any difference, thanks for the idea

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I have the same problem with not loading the images. If you are going to use jQuery I will recommend that you put your script (which loads the images) in

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // put all your jQuery goodness in here.  
 });
```

The fact is that your DOM object is not ready when you want to show or make operation with it.

Don't forget to call

```
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

in the head of your HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I can not use the `.ready` function, because the files have been created after the `.ready` occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

Having tried various options suggested here and some others, I researched, I decided to try putting the display of the images in a different function from the AJAX/PHP.  In other words instead of processing the images in the result function of the AJAX call, I just passed the results from the success function to another function.

This seems to have cured my not-found displays.

This may be a coincidence, with something else going on, because I am very poor in the knowledge of the flow of the DOM.